# iMac mid 2011 RAM upgrade compatability

Tags: imac, upgrade, memory

Is [this RAM](http://www.hardwareversand.de/articledetail.jsp?aid=121289&agid=1192&pvid=11azrtnu2c_hqw99otm&ref=58&lid=1&gclid=CL6z67TanLwCFQkd3goduF8Ayw) going to be compatible with a mid 2011 iMac 21.5"?

Answer (score 1):

The RAM you are pointing are DIMM. [Your iMac](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4621?viewlocale=en_US) is only compatible with the SODIMM form-factor.